# Why using compound interest formula gives (potentially) wrong answer in this instance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I was doing some catch up exercise on Khan academy and was given this seemingly simple looking problem

> Find the compound interest and the total amount after 4 years and 6 months if the interest is compounded annually.
>
> Principal = £100,000
>
> Rate of interest 10% percent per annum
>
> Calculate total amount and compound interest

I calculated it using compound interest formula:
$$ 100000(1.1)^{4.5} = 153556.10346 $$

But this turned out to be the wrong answer, the correct answer, as presented by Khan academy was this:
[khan academy answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKVjc.png)

153730.5

I can also arrive at this value by sort of using the compound interest formula for first 4 years, but then calculating interest for the last 6 months manually (0.1/2):
$$ 100000(1.1)^{4} = 146410 $$
$$ 146410 + ( 146410 \cdot 0.05 ) = 153730.5 $$

I still feel a bit unsatisfied, and feel I am not *really* understanding what's going on here and why would calculating the last step manually give a different answer.

Can you provide an explanation on why this formula should not apply on this case?

Comment: 5% interest for 6 months is not derivable from 10% interest per year. Each month's interest is (1.1)^(1/12), so six months' interest would be sqrt (1.1)

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg:  but OP's use of $1.1^{0.5}$ for the final half year does exactly this.  I agree with OP's answer and the recreation of the Khan answer demonstrates that it is wrong.

Comment: @NoChance points out in their answer that where you have "0.1/5" you meant to write "0.1/2" (thereby generating the 0.05 two lines later).

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was a typo

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Thanks for asking a good question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Khan academy answer seems to be derived from assumptions about how financial institutions operate. The various assumptions may reflect real-life finance (but not the mathematical viewpoint) or the mathematical viewpoint (but not real-life finance), and at least one is arguably based on information missing from the problem statement.

We assume there are no changes to the principal (such as deposits or withdrawals) during the four and a half years other than the crediting of interest.

At the end of four years, immediately after the fourth year's interest is credited,
the balance in the account should be, as you computed,

$$ 100000(1.1)^4 = 146410. $$

If you wait another six months and check the account balance again, I would expect still to see a balance of $146410.$
However, if you are allowed to **withdraw** the entire balance of the account at that time, you might be entitled to receive interest for the last six months.
(Many real-life investments such as savings bank accounts allow this.)

If you are entitled to interest for the last six months, the usual practice (as far as I know) is to prorate the interest, that is, if exactly half a year has passed since the previous interest payment then you receive exactly half of one year's interest.
That is $5\%$ of the balance after the last regular interest payment, in this case.

Since the question says nothing about whether the funds are withdrawn (or not) at the end of the four and a half years, however, the question is ill-formed.
While the answer might plausibly be a result that could occur in real life (if you can still find an investment that pays interest only annually, allows the investment to be liquidated in the middle of the year, and pays prorated interest for the final partial year), there's no way really to guess which of at least two plausible interpretations is meant. It's a bad question.

Comment: Thanks. I think this clears the confusion, and your explanation makes sense to me. I thought of this only in the context of a math problem and did not consider alternative contexts.

Comment: No bank would credit interest in this way to its depositors, though it might for its borrowers.

Comment: From an industry standpoint I can confirm it's not uncommon for large financial institutions to use 'pro-rata' annual compounding rates in models when dealing with fractions of a year. This is because the difference (here ~0.1%) is often not material in a model or because some contracts actually specify e.g. monthly payments in a 'pro-rata' manner.

Comment: re. _"Since the question says nothing about whether the funds are withdrawn (or not) at the end of the four and a half years, however, the question is ill-formed."_  -- meh, withdrawn or not, the number that matters for the total amount is what you _could_ withdraw if you pulled it all out. Looking at just the current number while ignoring the interest you're due to get anyway is only a part of it. Sure, in practice it might be you don't get anything until after the next full year, but that's a teaching question, and the extra 6 months isn't there just as a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

It is in the formulation:

> the interest is compounded annually.

That means you get your interest only after a full year has passed, so the interest received after 4 1/2 years is the same as that after 4 years.

Comment: This is the interpretation I would be most tempted to go with, but it's worth noting that the Khan academy answer does not use it either - so both numbers are wrong under this interpretation.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ah yes, you are right, I didn't read carefully.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov The Khan academy's answer is correct. It's quite standard for the interest to *accrue* monthly, but *compound* annualy.  This means that amount of the monthly accrual is $\ \frac{rS}{12}\ $, where $\ r\ $ is the per annum interest rate, and $\ S\ $ the sum of the principal and interest *accrued to the beginning of the year*.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I was unfamiliar with that convention, thank you. I suggest making your comment an answer!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov Yes, I am preparing an answer, but it will be a little while before I'll be able to finish it.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera But interest does not usually get *credited* to an account until the end of a compounding period, even if it is considered to accrue during the period.

Comment: @David K My choice of the word "standard" was perhaps an exaggeration.  Whether the interest gets credited only at the end of a compounding period or more frequently depends on the particular financial product.  For many years I have maintained a term deposit on which the interest compounded annually but which, could be *credited* at a frequency of $4$-weekly, $6$-monthly or annually, to be chosen whenever the term was renewed.

Comment: Typically, the fixed interest rate offered for the $4$-weekly crediting frequency was lower than that for the $6$-monthly or annual, so it would only be advantageous if you wanted to access the funds before the deposit matured.

Answer (score 2):

The period is 4.5 years.

We divide the calculation into 2 parts.

Part (A): The first 4 years - We can use the compound interest formula:

Compound Interest =$$ 100000 * (1.1)^{4} =  146,410.00 \tag A$$

Part (B): Treat the remaining 6 months using simple interest formula:

Six Months Interest = $$146410*(0.1)/2= 7,320.50 \tag B$$

The total amount at the end of 4.5 years is $(A)+(B)$:

$$ 146,410.00 + 7,320.50 = 153,730.5$$

Your issue was with:

> then calculating interest for the last 6 months manually (0.1/5)

You divided by $5$ not by $2$. We divide by $2$ because its a half year.

Comment: OP actually _did_ divide by 2 (despite a typo saying otherwise), so this doesn't add anything beyond what the OP said.

Comment: Sorry, "0.1/5" was a typo

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and the Khan answer is wrong.  The interest multiplier for six months should be $\sqrt {1.1} \approx 1.0488$.  If you apply that twice you get $1.1$ for an annual multiplier as you should.

Comment: I'm not aware of any financial instrument that computes interest for a partial compounding period in that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you compute and credit interest annually, you get an annual increment of interest. This is done for some financial instruments.

You can also compute and credit interest monthly. This used to be standard for savings accounts (on the "minimum monthly balance").

You can also compute interest daily (and typically, credit and compound monthly).

You could, now, with computer automation, compute and credit and compound daily, using fractional cents, since the small amount of interest credited daily would be lost if you discarded small amounts.

The difference between compounding daily and hourly is small. For numbers very close to 1, compounding interest is almost exactly the same as average interest. If the interest for a day is "1", then for a half day it is "1/2". In the limit, it becomes meaningless: you have to compound infinitely an infinitely small amount of money. But fortunately, the limit is bounded, and for a normal amount of interest over a year, the bound is very close to "calculated and compounded daily".

For this reason, we can use "compounding continuously" as an approximation for "compounding daily".  In the limit, calculating "compounding continuously, to get 10% per annum", over a half year, the equation is
$$ 100000(1.1)^{0.5} = 104880.884817 $$, and at the end of the second half of the year you would have 104881*104881= 110000.

Now let's try that compounding daily, at an interest rate of 0.026116 per day:
$$ 100000(1.00026116)^{365} = 110000 $$
$$ 100000(1.00026116)^{182} = 104867 $$
$$ 100000(1.00026116)^{182.5} = 104880 $$
... once you start dealing with days, half days and leap years start to matter, but the result for the half year is close to the result from the "compounding continuously" formula. To be exact, you just have to get the "0.5" years to match an exact number of days: you've got to be more exact than "0.5 years" (Note, the result for the full year is exact, because that's where we started: 10% per annum.)

If you don't match the fractional year to an exact number of days, you've got a fractional day, with the exact same problem you started with, except that difference between the "wrong" result and the "right" result is small. So lets try to see how big the error is:

$$ Interest for one day:  0.026116% $$
$$ Interest for half day (continuous): (0.00026116)^{0.5} = 0.00013057 $$
$$ Interest for half day (daily): (0.00026116)/2 = 0.00013058 $$
On £100000, that's 0.1 pence per half day: if you used the "wrong" formula to compare returns that compounded daily, that's the kind of error you'd get.

Savings banks still do "interest credited monthly" or "interest credited quarterly", and consequently still do "compounding monthly" or "compounding quarterly". "Compounding continuously" is easy to calculate *only when the balance is constant*. Once the balance starts moving, you have to do a separate interest calculation for every balance, so it's no easier than any other periodically credited account.

"Interest credited daily" is mostly only of value as a comparison rate for other short term investments. Very few financial instruments are actually constructed that way.

For real financial calculations, you have to know the interest rate, interest rate interval, the compounding interval, the date interval calculation (how long is a month?), the payment dates (not necessarily the same as the compounding or date-interval dates), the rounding rules (cents? dollars? lakh?) and balance calculation rules